# jQuery finding just the closest class to show a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having a small issue with my toggling. I have a bunch of yes and no answers and based on if they click yes or no there are more questions that appear. This was working fine until I had to move some of the yes and no questions inside a question that has already been answered.

My html looks sort of like this

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="authorCover">
        Are you amazing? (Optional)
    </label>
    <button class="btn btn-small btn-success coverBtn yesBtn">Yes</button>
    <button class="btn btn-small btn-danger coverBtn noBtn">No</button>
    <p class="clearix"></p>
    <div class="answYes">
      <label for="upload">
        Please Upload your amazing here!
      </label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" name="upload" value="" />
    </div><!--.answYes-->
    <div class="answNo">


   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="authorCover">
        Are you awesome? (Optional)
     </label>
     <button class="btn btn-small btn-success coverBtn yesBtn">Yes</button>
     <button class="btn btn-small btn-danger coverBtn noBtn">No</button>
     <p class="clearix"></p>
     <div class="answYes">
       <label for="awesome">
        Please Upload your awesomeness here
       </label>
       <input type="file" class="form-control" name="awesome" value="" />
     </div><!--.answYes-->
     <div class="answNo">no</div>
   </div><!--.form-group-->
  </div><!--.answNo-->
</div><!--.form-group-->
```

and my jQuery looks like this

```
$('.yesBtn').on('click', function(){
  $(this).parent().find('.answYes').toggle();
  $(this).parent().find('.answNo').hide();
  return false;
});

$('.noBtn').on('click', function(){
  $(this).parent().find('.answNo').toggle();
  $(this).parent().find('.answYes').hide();
  return false;
});
```

To make it a bit more clear I made a jsFiddel 
http://jsfiddle.net/pusKM/

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: use `show()` instead of `toggle()`

Comment: thats still doesn't solve my issue and plus I would have to add more code else where to get that to work. I'm really just using toggle as a short hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.closest('.form-group')` instead of `.parent()`

```
$('.yesBtn').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.answYes').toggle();
    $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.answNo').hide();
    return false;
});
$('.noBtn').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.answNo:first').toggle();
    $(this).closest('.form-group').find('.answYes').hide();
    return false;
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pusKM/2/)**

Comment: it's still showing the content in the second yes/no answer though

Comment: Yeah, thank you very much! That worked perfectly...I didn't know you could do a :first